# How to Prove Commutative Property of Maximum in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm extremely new to Isabelle so please have mercy.  How can I prove the commutative property of maximum with this function?

```
fun max :: "nat => nat => nat" where
"max 0 0 = 0" |
"max (Suc x) 0 = Suc x" |
"max 0 (Suc x) = Suc x" |
"max (Suc x) (Suc y) = Suc (max x y)"

lemma "max x y = max y x"
? ? ?
```

I know that it can be easily proven for

```
definition max :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"max x y = (if x ≥ y then x else y)"

lemma "max x y = max y x"
apply(simp add:max_def)
done
```

This is not a homework assignment.  I'm genuinely curious and would love to understand as much about Isabelle and mathematical proof as possible.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't forget to check the book Concrete Semantics (Nipkow and Klein). It is freely available online and its first 5 chapters are a practical introduction to Isabelle: http://www.concrete-semantics.org/

Comment: I stumbled on that book previously and am slowly making my way through.  Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You're welcome. I struggled to complete the first part a while ago. It's challenging but really worth the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way to prove some fact about a recursively-defined function is by induction, where the structure of the induction follows the structure of the recursive definition.

In Isabelle, you can do induction with the `induct` method. If you write `induct n` for a natural number `n`, you will get two cases: the case where `n = 0` and the case where `n` is the successor of something.

In this case, you should, however, use the induction rule provided for `max` by the function package, which is called `max.induct`. So, just do `apply (induction x y rule: max.induct)` on your goal and see what you are left with afterwards. This is sufficient for what you want to prove.

However, you already mentioned the alternative definition `if x ≥ y then x else y`. Some proofs (like associativity of `max`) are probably easier with that definition. In such cases, you can simply proof this alternative definition as

```
lemma max_altdef: "max x y = (if x ≥ y then x else y)"
```

and then use whichever definition is more convenient for you in every situation. The proof of `max_altdef` is also a simple induction.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you!  This solves my problem, and I will definitely consider alternate definitions to ease the burden of proofing in the future.